# how to get the multiple csv files on a line graph using Plotly python library to get the results on browser?

Tags: python, csv, graph, plotly, data-visualization

[image] I have multiple csv files for test_suites Synergy_graph22.csv, C7000_graph22.csv, Synergy-gen2_graph22.csv, like this i have 10 more csv files, which are having the same columns in all the files build_id and pass percent. **I need to plot the line graph for all those files. where build id is x-axis and pass-percent is y-axis. I need to get line graph for each csv file (mean for each test suite). each csv file corresponds to one test_suite.**

I was able to get the graph for only one csv file. I am able to get graph using matplotlib, but i want the graph on web page/browser, I got to know that we can use Plotly module/bookeh or any module that is able to get the same graph results on web would be helpful.

please help me to resolve this. below is the code i have used. **help me to convert the code using Plotly module to get the line graph for the csv files which mentioned above.**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
%matplotlib inline  

# graphing parameters
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)

p = Path(r'c:\Users\shivarad\Documents')  # path to files
files = list(p.rglob('*graph22.csv'))  # get files

# everything for here down, belongs in one Jupyter cell
plt.figure()
for f in files:  # iterate through files
    file_name = f.stem  # get filename
    df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype={'Pass Percentage': int, 'original_pass_percent': int})  # create 
    dataframe

    print(df.head())  # this is here to verify df has data; it can be commented out or removed

    plt.plot('build ID', 'Pass Percentage', data=df, label=file_name)  # plot the data from each file

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left')
plt.savefig('test.jpg')  # verify there's plot in the file
plt.show()  # outside the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fig = go.Figure()
for f in files: 
    file_name = f.stem  
    df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype={'Pass Percentage': int, 'original_pass_percent': 
         int})  
    print(df.head())  
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['build ID'], y=['Pass Percentage'],
                mode='lines',
                name=file_name))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Hi @nav610, Thank you for the response, But I am not able to see the line graph, It shows only blank graph without lines..Please help me to fix this

Comment: I have added the snap of the graph in the above the graph

Comment: Looks like I had typo, saying y = ['Pass Perccentage'], with two C's. Edited the code. Hopefully that fixes the issue.